# How to implement Python chatbot file into app or website?

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot

I hope you are all doing well, I have a chatbot here using TensorFlow, tflearn, NumPy, and nltk. It is supposed to be a mock waiter at the "Krusty Krab" which is supposed to take your order and deliver it to the restaurant. NLP (Natural Language Processing) was used. I was wondering if I could somehow implement it into an app or website? This is so a user can access it on any device at any time. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code. Thank you!

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.Lancaster import LancasterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

import NumPy
import tflearn
import TensorFlow
import random
import JSON
import pickle

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []

    for intent in data["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)

        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)


    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)


model.load("model.tflearn")

#model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=2000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
#model.save("model.tflearn")

def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1

    return numpy.array(bag)


def chat():
    print()
    print()
    while True:
        print("Bot: Welcome to the Krusty Krab, how are you today?")
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        gsynonyms = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets("good"):
          for l in syn.lemmas():
            gsynonyms.append(l.name())
        bsynonyms = []
        for syn in wordnet.synsets("bad"):
          for l in syn.lemmas():
            bsynonyms.append(l.name())

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]

        if results[results_index] > 0.7:
          for tg in data["intents"]:
            if tg['tag'] == tag:
              responses = tg['responses']
          print(random.choice(responses))
          break
        else:
          if inp in gsynonyms:
            print("Bot: That's good to hear!")
          elif inp in bsynonyms:
            print("Bot: Sorry to hear that.")
          else:
            print("Bot: I'm sorry, I don't understand.")


chat()

while True:
  print("Bot: (Please answer Yes/No) Do you have an allergy to Kelp, Coral, or Krab meat?")
  allergyconfirm = input("You: ")
  if allergyconfirm.lower() == "yes":
    print("Bot: What are you allergic to?")
    allergy = input("You: ")
    if allergy.lower() != "kelp" or allergy.lower() != "coral" or allergy.lower() != "krab" or allergy.lower() != "krab meat" or allergy.lower() != "meat":
      print("Bot: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Since you typed an allergy which doesn't interfere with our menu, I will automatically assume that our menu will be fine for you.")
      allergyconfirm = "no"
    break
  elif allergyconfirm.lower() == "no":
    print("Bot: All right!")
    break
  else:
    print("Bot: I'm sorry, I don't understand.")

ordersize = {}
totalcost = 0

def noallergy():
  print("Bot: What would you like to order? We have Kelp shakes, Coral bits, and our world-famous Krabby Patties.")
def kelpallergy():
  print("Bot: What would you like to order? We have Coral bits and our world-famous Krabby Patties.")
def coralallergy():
  print("Bot: What would you like to order? We have Kelp shakes and our world famous Krabby Patties.")
def kraballergy():
  print("Bot: What would you like to order? We have Kelp shakes and Coral bits.")


while True:
  if allergyconfirm.lower() == "no":
    noallergy()
  elif allergy.lower() == "kelp":
    kelpallergy()
  elif allergy.lower() == "coral":
    coralallergy()
  elif allergy.lower() == "krab" or allergy.lower() == "krab meat" or allergy.lower() == "meat":
    kraballergy()
  order = input("You: ")

  for i in range(0, len(order) - 6):
    if order[i:i+7].lower() == "nothing":
      print("Okay!")
      break

  if order.lower() == "kelp shake" or order.lower() == "coral bits":
    print("Bot: What size? We have small, medium, and large.")
    size = input("You: ")
    ordersize[order] = size
  elif order.lower() == "krabby patty":
    print("Bot: What size/version? We have single, double, and triple.")
    size = input("You: ")
    ordersize[order] = size

  if order.lower() == "kelp shake" and size.lower() == "small":
    totalcost += 1.00
  elif order.lower() == "kelp shake" and size.lower() == "medium":
    totalcost += 1.25
  elif order.lower() == "kelp shake" and size.lower() == "large":
    totalcost += 1.50
  elif order.lower() == "coral bits" and size.lower() == "small":
    totalcost += 1.00
  elif order.lower() == "coral bits" and size.lower() == "medium":
    totalcost += 1.25
  elif order.lower() == "coral bits" and size.lower() == "large":
    totalcost += 1.50
  elif order.lower() == "krabby patty" and size.lower() == "single":
    totalcost += 1.25
  elif order.lower() == "krabby patty" and size.lower() == "double":
    totalcost += 2.00
  elif order.lower() == "krabby patty" and size.lower() == "triple":
    totalcost += 3.00
  else:
    print("Bot: I'm sorry, I don't understand.")

  print("Bot: (Please answer Yes/No) Would you like anything else?")
  wouldlike = input("You: ")
  if wouldlike.lower() == "no":
    break
  elif wouldlike.lower() == "yes":
    print("Bot: All right!")
  else:
    print("Bot: I'm sorry, I don't understand.")

print("Bot: Okay, you ordered:")
for i in ordersize:
  print("Bot:", i, "-", ordersize[i])
if ordersize == {}:
  print("Bot: Nothing")
print("Bot: Your total cost is: $",totalcost)
```

Comment: _I was wondering if I could somehow implement it into an app or website_ - this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. I recommend searching for some tutorials on how to write an app or web interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty broad question, but one way to integrate this into a web application might be [Flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/).

I can't tell for certain, but it looks like your chatbot is stateless (that is, responses don't depend on previous inputs) which should make this straightforward. The basic architecture here would be a Flask application with a single route, which would look a bit like this (check the Flask documentation for more details).

```
from flask import request

# [chatbot setup code here]

@app.route('/chatbot' methods=['POST'])
def chatbot():
    inp = request.form['input']
    # [generate chatbot response here]
    return {'output': response}
```

(Your existing code would need to be adapted to store the response in a single string instead of using multiple commands.)

On the client side, you would want a basic "chat" front-end which sends input from a form to this route, and then displays the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into PySimpleGuiWeb.
I'm migrating my tkinter code for it.
You could create a gui for your bot and have it in web technology.
Good luck.